# Form.IO Form Builder style

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass, formio

I'm using Form.IO's Form builder component inside my react app and it's not really working, the styles are way off and I think something is missing!

Here is a small project with how I'm implementing it:

[form.io form builder](https://github.com/ralibardi/react-formio-form-builder)

Thanks!

P.S: Completely forgot to actually commit the code! Sorry! Just updated the repo

Answer (score 0):

You should install the React library for form.io . Do it by opening a terminal command line in your project and then run this command

```
npm install react-formio --save
```

than you could implement it within your project... Look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formio) to learn about this library.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to commit the actual code lol!

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a look at my repo https://github.com/VincenzoMarcovecchio/portfolio-v2/blob/master/src/components/About/About.jsx I made it my self and it works (with getform.io) It is fairly easy to set up too. P.s the link you have provided points to a create-react-app boilerplate which looks empty to me. Anyway have a good one.

Comment: Yeah sorry :'(! Thought I committed the changes 

Comment: The URL is dead, do you have a git repo, could you make it public?

Comment: Hey @Chief if you need any help let me know